# how to validate dynamic form inputs with watchers vue? Game of sums

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

Nowadays i'm coding a sum app but im having problems with the inputs validations. Im using Watcher to validate. I' trying to add sound and color if i could validate correctly.

1. github: https://github.com/RaPzoD1/Divertinumeros
2. Live Demo: https://divertinumeros.netlify.app/

I'm using this code to generate random numbers for sums

```
created () {
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
}
// console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 2)) + 2)
for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
  const total = getRandomInt(2, 21)
  // this.numRandom.push(getRandomInt(2, 20))
  const numero1 = getRandomInt(1, total)
  const newObj = {
    id: index,
    total,
    numero1,
    numero2: total - numero1
  }
  this.numRandom.push(newObj)
}
```

}
Im using this code to validate with watchers

```
  watch: {
respuesta: {
  handler (newValue, oldValue) {
    const valores = Object.values(newValue)
    const operaciones = [...this.numRandom]
    for (let i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        // console.log(operaciones[i].numero1)
        if (operaciones[i].numero1 === parseInt(valores[i])) {
          console.log('correcto', operaciones[i].numero1, valores[i])
          // this.playSuccess()
          // const element = document.getElementById(i)
          // // console.log(element)
          // element.classList.add('correcto')
        } else {
          console.log('fallaste', operaciones[i].numero1, valores[i])
          // this.playError()
          // const element = document.getElementById(i)
          // element.classList.add('incorrecto')
          // // console.log(element)
        }
      } else {
        // console.log(operaciones[i].numero2)
        if (operaciones[i].numero2 === parseInt(valores[i])) {
          console.log('correcto', operaciones[i].numero2, valores[i])
          // this.playSuccess()
          // const element = document.getElementById(i)
          // element.classList.add('correcto')
          // // console.log(element)
        } else {
          console.log('fallaste', operaciones[i].numero2, valores[i])
          // this.playError()
          // const element = document.getElementById(i)
          // // console.log(element)
          // element.classList.add('incorrecto')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

But when the inputs change the watchers re validate many times

[image]

some tip to validate correctly?

Comment: I've used watch a few times, and have never seen an example with that much code and logic.  I recommend trying to move most of the logic out of the watcher, possibly creating a method or computed variable.

Answer (score 1):

I was tinking about @Tim 's comment, and thats right i was too greedy validating so much fields at same time, that's why i split the code and its works much better.

```
 <section id="suma_libre">
    <div
      class="fila_circulo"
      v-for="numero in numRandom"
      :key="numero.id"
      :id="numero.id"
    >
      <FilaSuma :number="numero"/>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I change validate 4 at a time for just 1 with this code:

```
 data () {
return {
  number1: '',
  number2: '',
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false
}
```

},

```
  watch: {
number1: _.debounce(function (newNumber1) {
  this.number.numero1 === parseInt(newNumber1)
    ? this.playSuccess()
    : this.playError()
}, 500),
number2: _.debounce(function (newNumber2) {
  this.number.numero2 === parseInt(newNumber2)
    ? this.playSuccess()
    : this.playError()
}, 500)
```

},